# Handling custom control UI element using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

My UI control looks like a button and when we click on it will expand and will act as Multi-Select drop down list.

Can anyone let me know on how can I automate this control through Selenium?

**Edit** (adding code for OP from comment section):

The following is what I have tried so far:

```
<button class="dropdown-btn btn btn-default pull-left " aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" ng-class="{'disabled':multiDictionaryCtrl.isDisabled }"> <span class="pull-left ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding" ng-model="multiDictionaryCtrl.selectedDictionaryItem">Select</span> <span class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-down pull-right"></span> <span class="fa pull-right"></span> </button>
```

**Description:**

When you click on this button, it will expand and will act as a drop-down control where we can select options in it.

Comment: You have provided us ZERO information to help you. Please read through [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: <button class="dropdown-btn btn btn-default pull-left " aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" ng-class="{'disabled':multiDictionaryCtrl.isDisabled }">
<span class="pull-left ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding" ng-model="multiDictionaryCtrl.selectedDictionaryItem">Select</span>
<span class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-down pull-right"></span>
<span class="fa pull-right"></span>
</button> when you click on his button it will expand and will act as a drop-down control where we can select options in it

Comment: There is a "edit" button in your question that allows you (or other editors) to add / remove contents. I have added the code and the comment for you, this time. Good luck with the question.